# Deploy gradle project to nexus via bamboo

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, nexus, bamboo, gradlew

I have a java project with gradle, and Im using Bamboo as my CI/CD.
My build plan makes the jar, and my deploy plan (supposes to) deploy the jar to nexus. My build works perfectly, and creates the artifacts (the jar, the `build.gradle` file, the `gradle.properties` file and the `gradle.settings` file).

When I want to run my deploy plan, I run the `uploadArchives` command in bamboo. This command also make the `jar` command run, which destroy my jar (makes it 261 bytes). The solution I found is just tell gradle to skip the `jar` command (using `-x jar`), but I feel that there is a better solution.

Is there a special command in gralde to make it work? or is there a way to tell gradle to run a specific command without its preceding commands? maybe something like maven command to upload 3rd party libraries? I have searched eveywhere but couldn't find.

Thnaks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's how Gradle works and it depends how you configured your builds. But generally speaking, you can create an task which publishes just a file (it doesn't depend on anything). You'll need to use a *maven-publish* plugin. E.g. let's consider the following configuration

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

group= "gradle-test"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
task produce {
  ext {
    outputFile = file("$buildDir/file.txt")
  }
  outputs.file  outputFile
  doLast {
    outputFile  << "Hello World!"
  }
}

task zipGreeting(type: Zip) {
    from produce.outputs
}

publishing {
    publications {
        newGreeting(MavenPublication) {
            artifact zipGreeting
        }
        oldGreeting(MavenPublication) {
            artifact {
              produce.outputFile
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the following configuration task `publishNewGreetingPublicationToMavenLocal` depends on `zipGreeting` and `produce` (because it depends on `produce`'s output) so in the end Gradle will invoke them if their outputs are not up to date (I suppose this happens with your `jar` task -> Gradle up-to-date check depends on a local `.gradle` cache directory)

But `publishOldGreetingPublicationToMavenLocal`  doesn't have explicit dependency on any other task so if you call `gradle publishOldGreetingPublicationToMavenLocal`. Gradle will try to find the mentioned file and just upload it to Maven Local. Obviously, it will fail if the file isn't there.

Comment: So you say that I should specify the artifact as the jar file in the build folder? In that case gradle will not run the "jar" task?
Do you know what is considered as best practice?

Comment: It generally depends on what you want to achieve. You haven't written why your jar is being destroyed by a deploy plan 
I can see that artifacts shouldn't be rebuilt during deployment phase, therefore Gradle should use artifacts from build plans. But those run on a different agents and Gradle doesn't know your jars are up to date.
Both (mine and yours solution) will probably work fine. However, in my opinion, mine states the intentions clear, "Yeah, I expect this file to be uploaded". In your case, just do this task, but ignore any dependencies it has and assume everything is there already"